# Cell modem "already in use" in W10 Creators Update 1703

Tags: networking, usb

I have a USB Dongle/Cellular Modem (A fingersized device that plugs into a computer via USB. You put a cellphone SIM card in it and use it to connect to the internet via a cellphone network).

I have been using it for years, but since Windows Creator update, I cannot launch an internet connection with it on my main computer (a Lenovo laptop, Win 10 Home Build 15063.332, 64bit, i7-4300U). I use a propriatery "Connection Manager" app to launch a connection, and on clicking "Connect" it returns the error "The modem (or other connecting device) is already in use or is not configured properly".

I also have a tablet (Win 10 Home Build 15063.332, Atom Z3725G "32-bit OS, x64-based processor"). Everything fine works just fine on that. Same drivers, same "Connection Manager" app and settings.

I assume there is some conflict on the laptop, but don't know what or where to find it. I had a poke around Windows settings, but none of them seem to deal with a USB modem. They only talk about old-school landline modems or wifi.

I have done all the usual uninstall/reinstall drivers stuff and have also tried (almost*) everything from this list, to no avail.
https://appuals.com/fix-error-633-modem-or-other-connecting-device-is-already-in-use/

(* Except #1 - I can't remove the proprietary "Connection Manager" app because it is the only way I have of launching a connection to the internet.  I don't know a way of launching a connection from native Windows when using a USB modem).  I *have* uninstalled and reinstalled the "Connection Manager" app.

(btw, I don't see the "633" part of the error message, as I am seeing it through the Connection Manager app, not through native Windows. Presumably the app strips out the "633" part before reporting the error).

If I revert Windows back to Anniversary version, its fine. If I then "upgrade" again to Creators version, the problem returns. I'm sure MS won't let me stay on Anniversary Edition forever, so I need to fix this. Everything works fine on the other (Tablet) machine with same OS.

any suggestions ?

TIA

Comment: I would contact the author of the, propriatery Connection Manager, and report the incompatability with it and the current version of Windows 10.  It is very likely the application itself is at fault.

Comment: But it works fine on the tablet computer with the same (version of) Windows 10!

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix, through this Registry Hack.  Apparently MS are aware of the problem and are working on it. 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/dial-up-error-633-wbuild-15063-1703-creators-pro/2c5b280e-e246-4105-b8e6-58e413d2668e

Comment: sightly different,  https://superuser.com/questions/1287862/verizon-vz-access-manager-error-633-caused-by-creators-update-1703/1287863#1287863