# Verizon VZ Access Manager Error 633 caused by Creators Update 1703

Tags: networking, usb, vpn, modem

How to fix the Error 633?

After reading may Google results saying the same as [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1217195/cell-modem-already-in-use-in-w10-creators-update-1703/1217976#1217976), [this unanswered Microsoft question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-winapps-appscat_tools/verizon-vzaccess-wont-connect-after-creators/8ca86534-5898-48e2-864c-2dfc2d0d9e9f?auth=1), and opening trouble ticket #NRB000009256915 with Verizon Wireless - the answer was not apparent.

Since the system is up to date, and the SeLoadDriverPrivilege fix was is already in place. The reserve ports was not, but fixing that made no change.

Answer (score 0):

The solution appears to be a simple uninstall / reinstall of VZ Access Manager. I am using v7.10.0.1.2813b.RIM on Windows 10 1709 16299.15 .

I did apply the tcpip reserved port 1723, removed the blackberry, COM3/4 devices from the device manager too. I did test these before removing / reinstalling VZ Access Manager without success.